# Shutting down nodejs microservice gracefully when using Docker Swarm

Tags: node.js, docker-swarm, koa2

I am have multiple micro services written in `Nodejs Koa` running in `Docker Swarm`.

Since container orchestration tools like Kubernetes or Swarm can scale up and down services instantly, I have a question on gracefully shutting down Nodejs service to prevent unfinished running process.

Below is the flow I can think of:

1. sending a SIGNINT signal to each worker process, **Does docker swarm
   send `SIGNINT` to worker when scaling down service**?
2. the worker are responsible to catch the signal, cleanup or free any
   used resource and finish the its process, **How can I stop new api
   request, wait for any running process to finish before shutting
   down?**

   Some code below from reference:

   ```
   process.on('SIGINT', () => {
     const cleanUp = () => {
       // How can I clean resources like DB connections using Sequelizer
     }

     server.close(() => {

       cleanUp()
       process.exit()
     })

     // Force close server after 5secs, `Should I do this?`
     setTimeout((e) => {
       cleanUp()
       process.exit(1)
     }, 5000)
   })
   ```

Comment: I believe Docker Swarm sends a SIGTERM and then a SIGKILL, so you might want to move your code out to a `process.on('SIGTERM', () => {})`

Answer (score 0):

I created a library (https://github.com/sebhildebrandt/http-graceful-shutdown) that can handle graceful shutdowns as you described. Works well with Express and Koa.

This package also allows you to create function (should return a promise) to additionally clean up things like DB stuff, ... here some example code how to use it:

```
const gracefulShutdown = require('http-graceful-shutdown');
...
server = app.listen(...);
...

// your personal cleanup function - this one takes one second to complete
function cleanup() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log('... in cleanup')
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('... cleanup finished');
        resolve();
    }, 1000)       
  });
}

// this enables the graceful shutdown with advanced options
gracefulShutdown(server,
    {
        signals: 'SIGINT SIGTERM',
        timeout: 30000,
        development: false,
        onShutdown: cleanup,
        finally: function() {
            console.log('Server gracefulls shutted down.....')
        }
    }
);
```

I personally would increase the final timeout from 5 secs to higher value (10-30 secs). Hope that helps.